# Doing mapping from range of numbers to words

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have seen many examples where there is required some mapping from number to word, or the opposite direction.

In my case I want to do mapping from a range of values to words

I have a dictionary `intelligence = {"John" : 100 , "Mike" : 80, "Peter" : 150}`

I use this function:

```
a = list()
for name,iq in intelligence.items():    
    if iq<=100:
        smartness = "low iq"
        a.append((name,iq),smartness ))
    elif c>=100 and c<=95:
        smartness = "mid"
        a.append((name,iq),smartness ))
    else:
        smartness = "high"
        a.append((name,iq),smartness ))
print a
```

as you can see the code is a bit redundant, any more pythonic way to achieve this result? Ore maybe a completely different approach that is better?

After the EDIT

```
a = list()
for name,iq in intelligence.items():    
    if iq<=100:
        smartness = "low iq"
    elif c>=100 and c<=95:
        smartness = "mid"
    else:
        smartness = "high"
    a.append((name,iq),smartness ))
print a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def iq_to_distance(iq):
     if iq<=95: return "low"
     if iq<=100: return "mid"
     return "high"

for name,iq in intelligence.items():
    print {'name': name, 'iq': iq, 'distance': iq_to_distance(iq)}
```

output:

```
{'iq': 80, 'distance': 'low', 'name': 'Mike'}
{'iq': 100, 'distance': 'mid', 'name': 'John'}
{'iq': 150, 'distance': 'high', 'name': 'Peter'}
```

note that I've changed the numbers a little because `elif c>=100 and c<=95:` will always be False.

or one liner:

```
[{'name': name, 
  'iq': iq, 
  'distance': iq<=95 and "low" or iq<=100 and "mid" or "high"}
 for name,iq in intelligence.items()]
```

output:

```
[{'iq': 80, 'distance': 'low', 'name': 'Mike'}, 
 {'iq': 100, 'distance': 'mid', 'name': 'John'}, 
 {'iq': 150, 'distance': 'high', 'name': 'Peter'}]
```